# Where can I find a “Théorème du singe” pictorial representation?

Tags: anglais

There already exists in English an illustrated picture of [Théorème du singe](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th%C3%A9or%C3%A8me_du_singe). I was wondering if I could find a similar one in French. I know it is somewhere out there in a random server's heap but I genuinely doubt my google searching skills. In case someone wants a glance at the English one, [here](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/6828/was-the-experiment-with-five-monkeys-a-ladder-a-banana-and-a-water-spray-cond) is a link to the same on one of our sister site.

Comment: This is off-topic here (the question is not about the French Language), [cogsci.se] might be a better place to ask, but I haven't read their FAQ yet.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez I dont get it ! I didnt call for a discussion on the topic mentioned .I just wanted to find the link to the french illustration if it existed already . IMHO   the skeptics have discussed its aspect in detail .

Comment: And the down voter , please cite why when you downvote ! I would genuinely like to know  if there is yet another reason  than the one cited by Stéphane . Now , this sure is confusing.

Comment: @Geekasaur questions closed as off-topic automatically get one downvote from the system…

Comment: This would be on-topic IMHO if it were a request for a short, tricky sentence in another language.  However, there is a lot of relatively simple English in the linked diagram.  It could be translated into French by somebody reasonably competent, or even Google Translate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost the same images, but with the text in French, can be found [here](http://ingeniblagues.free.fr/personnalite/paradigme_singes/paradigme_singes.php).

Comment: Just what I was looking for :) Thanks